# SMS forwarded to email just shows up in SMS again?

Tags: email, sms

I have a SMS thread with text and photos.  Want to forward the thread to my email.  So I do the following:

1. tap and hold on message, then get popup at bottom for COPY, SAVE, MORE...
2. Click MORE... choose items to forward,
3. click forward arrow and
4. field opens to enter email address.
5. enter address and touch blue up arrow to send

Then message appears on my iPhone as an SMS again, not into my email.  I have tried 3 email address and they keep appearing in my SMS.

How do I get it to go to my real email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forward button will only forward to SMS.

Alternatively, you can copy the messages and paste them into a new me

Comment: Yep, cut and paste into new email piece by piece...